# Cannot subset data frame after reading with fread()

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I am trying to subset a table named `cars`, as shown below. I do not want the `Country` column in my subtable so I used `[,-1]` to delete the first column, but instead it assigned my new variable `cars.use` to `-1`. What happened here?

```
> library(data.table)
> cars <- fread('cars.csv', header = TRUE)
> typeof(cars)
[1] "list"
> head(cars)
Country                       Car  MPG Weight Drive_Ratio Horsepower Displacement Cylinders
1:    U.S.        Buick Estate Wagon 16.9  4.360        2.73        155          350         8
2:    U.S. Ford Country Squire Wagon 15.5  4.054        2.26        142          351         8
3:    U.S.        Chevy Malibu Wagon 19.2  3.605        2.56        125          267         8
4:    U.S.    Chrysler LeBaron Wagon 18.5  3.940        2.45        150          360         8
5:    U.S.                  Chevette 30.0  2.155        3.70         68           98         4
6:   Japan             Toyota Corona 27.5  2.560        3.05         95          134         4
> cars.use <- cars[,-1]
> cars.use
[1] -1
```

Comment: Working with data.table is faster and better once you learn it. Since you are already using _fread_, I am guessing you are aware that this is much faster than using read.table. So to remove a column in the language of data.table you could use the following command: `cars[ , Country := NULL]`. (see also @akrun comment below)

Comment: Fyi, you'll want to use `class(cars)` instead of `typeof(cars)` most of the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `fread`, we are getting a `data.table`.  To subset, a `data.table`,  `with=FALSE` can be used.

```
cars[,-1, with=FALSE]
```

It is described in `?data.table`

> By default with=TRUE and j is evaluated within the frame of x; column
>   names can be used as variables. When with=FALSE j is a character
>   vector of column names or a numeric vector of column positions to
>   select, and the value returned is always a data.table. with=FALSE is
>   often useful in data.table to select columns dynamically.

#### data

```
 cars <- data.table(Col1= 1:5, Col2= 6:10)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this problem in your call to `fread()`.

If you change your `fread()` call to drop the first column by name (or by number), the column will be skipped upon reading.

```
fread("cars.csv", drop = "Country", header = TRUE)
```

The reason you are having problems subsetting is because `fread()` returns a data **table** by default. If you need a data **frame**, change the `data.table` argument to `FALSE`.

```
cars <- fread("cars.csv", header = TRUE, data.table = FALSE)
```

Now we have a data frame, and the code `cars[,-1]` that you used will work.  And if you want to drop the column and return a data frame, combine these two.

```
fread("cars.csv", drop = "Country", header = TRUE, data.table = FALSE)
```

See `help(fread)` for further details.

Answer (score 1):

One option is setting your all column Country to NULL. This can be done as follows:

```
# Create dataframe
df <- read.delim(text='
Country Car MPG Weight Drive_Ratio Horsepower Displacement Cylinders
U.S. BuickEstateWagon 16.9 4.360 2.73 155 350 8
U.S. FordCountrySquireWagon 15.5 4.054 2.26 142 351 8
U.S. ChevyMalibuWagon 19.2 3.605 2.56 125 267 8
U.S. ChryslerLeBaronWagon 18.5 3.940 2.45 150 360 8
U.S. Chevette 30.0 2.155 3.70 68 98 4
Japan ToyotaCorona 27.5 2.560 3.05 95 134 4', sep=' ')

#> df
#  Country                    Car  MPG Weight Drive_Ratio Horsepower
#1    U.S.       BuickEstateWagon 16.9  4.360        2.73        155
#2    U.S. FordCountrySquireWagon 15.5  4.054        2.26        142
#3    U.S.       ChevyMalibuWagon 19.2  3.605        2.56        125
#4    U.S.   ChryslerLeBaronWagon 18.5  3.940        2.45        150
#5    U.S.               Chevette 30.0  2.155        3.70         68
#6   Japan           ToyotaCorona 27.5  2.560        3.05         95
#  Displacement Cylinders
#1          350         8
#2          351         8
#3          267         8
#4          360         8
#5           98         4
#6          134         4

# Remove the 'Country' columns from the dataframe 
df$Country <- NULL

#> df
#                     Car  MPG Weight Drive_Ratio Horsepower Displacement
#1       BuickEstateWagon 16.9  4.360        2.73        155          350
#2 FordCountrySquireWagon 15.5  4.054        2.26        142          351
#3       ChevyMalibuWagon 19.2  3.605        2.56        125          267
#4   ChryslerLeBaronWagon 18.5  3.940        2.45        150          360
#5               Chevette 30.0  2.155        3.70         68           98
#6           ToyotaCorona 27.5  2.560        3.05         95          134
#  Cylinders
#1         8
#2         8
#3         8
#4         8
#5         4
#6         4
```

Comment: As the OP is dealing with `data.table`, if we want to change 2nd and 3rd column to NULL `setDT(df)[, 2:3 := NULL]`